# After install ubuntu desktop still not runing GUI

Tags: apt, gui

Can someone help me what am i doing wrong. I want to install ubuntu desktop on ubuntu server 14.04.4 LTS from terminal. After `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` i made `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` then i made `sudo reboot`. But after server reboots i should see graphical login screen, right? But i don't, i still get normal window login like before [login terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snX68.png)

Comment: Install xserver-xorg-core and xserver-xorg

Comment: xserver-xorg-core and xserver-xorg is already the newest version.This is what i get...still nothing...

Comment: `sudo apt-get upgrade` does not upgrade everything, have you tried also running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`?

Comment: yes i tried also with sudo apt-get dist-upgrade..no luck...